# SAP NetWeaver ABAP 7.51 install failed (Installation of NPL failed... )

Tags: linux, installation, virtualbox, abap, netweaver

I am trying to install ABAP server on my system but it's failing continuously due to only one error:

> Installation of NPL failed .Please check log files in /tmp/sapinst_instdir

Please, can anybody let me know how to check this log files so that I can find the reason for installation failure.

I have downloaded ABAP 7.51 SP02, still I'm not able to install.

I am using Win7 and installing ABAP on Oracle Virtualbox (OpenSUSE 64-bit).

Please your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following conditions are fulfilled on your Linux system:

- GCC installed? if not -> sudo zypper install gcc
- Shared memory >= 4GB? if not -> mount -o remount,size=4G /dev/shm
- uuidd installed and running?
- password complex enough (lowercase, uppercase, number and special char)?
- English(US) as system language?